# «Трубу часто прорывало»

Tags: выбор-слов

Трубу часто прорывало. Можно так сказать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, так можно говорить.

[**прорывать**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/230555/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
**II** *несов. перех.*
2.1. Сильным напором разрушать препятствие.
2.2. ***безл. разг.* О выходе скопившейся жидкости из чего-либо лопнувшего.**

Ледниковая плотина не могла сдерживать такого объёма воды, в результате чего несколько раз плотину прорывало.

Как сообщает газета «Сельская новь», дамбу прорывало уже два раза: в 1998 и 2004 годах.

По словам жильцов, трубу горячего теплоснабжения, расположенную на чердаке дома, прорывало уже несколько раз.